# Can this SQL Server CTE be expressed with a "simpler" basic query?

Tags: sql-server-2012

So that I can union all or join it to a larger outer query of some kind?

```
-- Get purchase order due date for first purchase order after today which completes a cumulative sum satisfying demand which currently exceeds inventory supply
with cte as 
(
    select
        t1.itemcode as itemcode, 
        t1.dscription as itemname, 
        t1.quantity as quantity, 
        (select sum(t6.quantity)
         from por1 t6
         inner join opor t7 on t6.docentry = t7.docentry
         where t7.docduedate <= t2.docduedate
           and t7.docduedate > getdate()
           and t6.itemcode = 'item001') as totalqty,
        t2.docduedate as eta
    from 
        por1 t1
    inner join 
        opor t2 on t1.docentry = t2.docentry
    where 
        t1.itemcode = 'item001'
        and t2.docduedate > getdate()
)
select 
    cte.itemcode, cte.itemname, 
    convert(char(10), min(cte.eta), 101)
from 
    cte
where 
    totalqty > 55  -- I don't want this to be literal, the outer join would supply this as a calculated value
group by 
    cte.itemcode, cte.itemname
```

Re the outer query (which isn't included above because I haven't been able to join an outer query to the cte - I don't know that you can), I'd like it to calculate the amount, currently shown as 55, from the outer query and control which itemcodes to return based on a filtered list from an outer query instead of choosing just one literal itemcode (as above), for example.

I made various attempts to get totalqty using a having clause with no success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the result of what TotalQty is, or do you only want to use it as a condition?

If it's the former, I would say the CTE way is the best.  Otherwise, I would reframe it as a WHERE EXISTS clause on the select going into TotalQty, like `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SUM(T6.Quantity) [...] HAVING SUM(T6.Quantity) > 55)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @j.i.h. I mainly need it as a condition (I can probably live without also returning its value)I hadn't even thought of a where exists clause.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer to include the subquery where exists. I will try that in a little bit and update things here, thanks.

Comment: If you need the result also, you can just put the same subquery after your `SELECT` (minus the `HAVING` of course, since it will already be true since it's a condition of the `WHERE`).

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice tip, I will try that. Having the result helps with testing the query.

Comment: In `SELECT TOP 1` form, though the more I think about it for some reason I think it might not work.  If you actually want the result you should actually not use a `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...)` and refactor it back as a `JOIN`, the correct `GROUP BY` will give you the `SUM()` you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out.